# Komodo IDE 7 crashes on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: python, ubuntu, crash, openssl, komodo

Starting Komodo IDE 7 on Ubuntu 11.10 crashes in `libcrypto.so` during startup (see [this forum discussion](http://community.activestate.com/node/7538)):

```
#0  0xb121ffbc in EVP_PKEY_CTX_dup () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#1  0xb12121f6 in EVP_MD_CTX_copy_ex () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#2  0xb1212362 in EVP_MD_CTX_copy () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#3  0xb0e93c4d in ?? () from .../Komodo-IDE-7/lib/python/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so
#4  0xb0e93fc9 in ?? () from .../Komodo-IDE-7/lib/python/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so
#5  0xb549ba2d in PyCFunction_Call () from .../Komodo-IDE-7/lib/mozilla/libpython2.6.so
```

How can I get it to run successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On investigation, this happens when calling a function in the `_hashlib` module. This module is a builtin module in the standard Ubuntu python install (see `sys.builtin_module_names`), so the `_hashlib.so` that exists under `lib/python/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so` is not part of the Ubuntu python build.

You can fix this by recompiling that module from the standard Python sources:

```
export KOMODO_DIR=/home/davidf/Applications/Komodo-IDE-7
hg clone http://hg.python.org/cpython
cd cpython
hg checkout v2.6.5
(
    cd $KOMODO_DIR/lib/python/lib
    # handle no libssl.so
    ln -s /lib/libssl.so.0.9.8
    ln -s ./libssl.so.0.9.8 libssl.so
    # save the original _hashlib library
    cd python2.6/lib-dynload/
    mv _hashlib.so _hashlib.so.orig
)
# cd to python src for python 2.6.5
./configure --prefix $KOMODO_DIR/lib/python/

# step here to patch setup.py as @jalefkowit describes
# ...

# build and copy result to komodo's lib-dynload directory
$KOMODO_DIR/lib/python/bin/python setup.py build_ext
cp build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/_hashlib.so $KOMODO_DIR/lib/python/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/
```

Caveats:

- I didn't actually use the above script; it's a recreation. There may be mistakes :)
- You need the CPython 2.6.5 sources; you can get these some other way if you like
- There is probably a shorter, and simpler way to do this
- This will build all the Python extension modules, not just the one you need
- On my Ubuntu 11.10, there's a `libssl.so.0.9.8`, but no `libssl.so`. The above linking allows the Python build to find them.
- This actually works on my machine, but for 64-bit / another release, you may need some adjustments

Comment: this worked for me too with ubuntu 11.10 32bit edition thank's david :)

Comment: This worked for me on two machines in February-March, but it does not work on my new machine with the latest Ubuntu 11.10. I get: "Failed to find the necessary bits to build these modules:
_bsddb             _sqlite3           _tkinter        
bsddb185           dbm                gdbm            
sunaudiodev        zlib                               
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.


Failed to build these modules:
crypt              nis" when building cpython 2.6.5.

Comment: @hughdbrown: I think I've found a solution to make this work on Ubuntu 11.10. The problem appears to be related to [Ubuntu's move towards multiarch support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec), which involved moving a bunch of system files to new locations. You need to add a few lines to cpython's setup.py so that it can find the directory where your system libraries live now. [Here's a diff that shows the exact changes to make to the setup.py file.](http://bugs.python.org/file21465/d504ca7e0fe5.diff) (It'll still gripe about missing bits when you run it, but _hashlib.so will build anyway.)

Comment: @jalefkowit: yes, I saw your comments on support.activestate.com [http://support.activestate.com/node/7538]. I have applied your fixes and Komodo is now working for me. Thanks a lot. This was the hardest thing to get running of all the things I have installed on my new Ubuntu box.

Comment: @jalefkowit: please feel free to edit the solution above to incorporate your changes